# Scala Print Map in Order

Tags: scala, dictionary, match

I have a Map[String,String] and I would like to print it in a particular order depending on the keys. For example I would like to print the value of id, name, address. So I would like to match my keys to "id","name", "address" and then print the values at each of these keys. I have the following code but it doesn't work:

```
articlesmap.keys match{
    case ("id") => println(articlesmap.get("id"))
        case ("name") => println(articlesmap.get("name"))
        case ("address") => println(articlesmap.get("address"))
 }
```

Comment: why pattern matching? why not just the `println` statements?

Comment: I find really useful what @nimda pointed out. Regardless of alternative solutions, you're trying to match on the `keys` of the map, which is a `Iterator[String]`; *that* is the exact reason you're not getting the expected result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `for`:

```
for { 
  k <- Seq("id", "name", "address") // the keys in the order you want to print them.
  v <- articlesmap.get(k) 
} println (k+ " is " + v)
```

If you just want to print values, `collect` will do fine:

```
Seq("id", "name", "address") collect articlesmap foreach println
```

`collect` is better than `map` id you can't be certain that a key is actually in the map.

Answer (score 3):

here is the simplest solution as I know:

```
scala>  val keys = Seq("id", "name", "address") 
keys: Seq[java.lang.String] = List(id, name, address)

scala>  val articlesmap = Map("id" -> 1, "name" -> "john", "address" -> "some address")
articlesmap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Any] = Map(id -> 1, name -> john, address -> some address)

scala>  keys map articlesmap foreach println
1
john
some address

scala>  val keys = Seq("name", "id", "address")
keys: Seq[java.lang.String] = List(name, id, address)

scala>  keys map articlesmap foreach println
john
1
some address
```

Answer (score 2):

Variable articlesmap.keys is of type `Iterable[String]`, but your case matches are matching on type `String`. Try this instead:

```
def mapTest(map: Map[String, String]) {
    map.keys.foreach {
      case ("id") => println(map.get("id"))
      case ("name") => println(map.get("name"))
      case ("address") => println(map.get("address"))
    }
  }                                            

  val mapper = Map("id" -> "123", "name" -> "Bob", "address" -> "123 Fake Street")

  mapTest(mapper)

  // => Some(123)
  //    Some(Bob)
  //    Some(123 Fake Street)
```

Comment: The order is not what I want, the order is what is in the map hence the purpose is defeated, I would like to print it in the order I want.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an `OrderedMap` or you could sort the `keys` and process the result of that sort.